# Is return type deduction possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a function, *not necessarily templatised*:

```
T foo(Y bar);
```

where `T` and `Y` are types.

I can use `decltype(bar)` to get the type of `bar`. So I can write code like

`decltype(bar) anotherBar;`

But is there a way of my getting the return type? `decltype(return)` would make grammatical sense.

Comment: Unless you are creating a macro, just `T` should do

Comment: `decltype(foo(bar))`?

Comment: I *am* using a macro ;-) (Actually some JNI stuff).

Comment: That's not what `decltype(auto)` does.

Comment: @YogiBear: Besides what DevSolar said, I think I misunderstood the meaning of the proposal at first and I don't think it can be used that way after all. You can declare a function with `decltype(auto)` and the return type will be deduced by the `return` statement. Which is other way around compared to what you want. I removed the comment since it was not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you can use trailing return types, like:

```
auto foo(Y bar) -> decltype(some_expr(bar)) {
    return some_expr(bar);
}
```

The need to make it trailing is only because the expression depends on `bar` that is declared as an argument, and does not exist where the return type is defined.

C++14 provides (or will once approved) a simpler approach in which the compiler shall deduce the type of the function:

```
auto foo(Y bar) {
    return some_expr(bar);
}
```

Note that even if the standard allows for this, the fact that the type is not spelled out in the declaration has some possibly unwanted effects. For starters, you cannot declare that function without providing the definition (the return type is deduced looking at the body, without body the declaration would not have a return type). Additionally, this is problematic if there are multiple return statements [I don't recall the exact details here]

In the case of a template function, the type of the return expression cannot be known until the template arguments are substituted and the function instantiated, which is *after* substitution, and thus a deduced return type cannot be used in an SFINAE context.

While C++14 is not yet approved, some compilers might already implement this feature, check the documentation of your compiler.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using VS2012 which doesn't support C++11 completely (no brace initialisation, no constant expressions, no deletion of constructors), so I doubt it'll support this!

Comment: With all due respect, I fail to see how this (nonetheless well-written) answer actually pertains to the issue in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see it either.

Comment: @rubenvb I imagine it was more appropriate when the question title was [Is return type deduction possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23760057/2).

Comment: @Casey regardless the title, the question body was quite clear.

Comment: @rubenvb: I might have misunderstood the question, my interpretation is that the only context where you don't know the return type is when defining it, and this is what the answer tackles: can the deduced type be deduced? Yes in C++14, not in C++11, but you can use `decltype` for that.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the call expression of the function itself as `decltype`'s arg:

```
decltype(foo(bar))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/936b1369041c8861):

```
#include <type_traits>

constexpr void foo();

static_assert(std::is_same<void, decltype(foo())>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(foo()), std::result_of<decltype(foo)&(/*argtypes*/)>::type>::value, "nope");

int main(){}
```

I don't know why you'd use `decltype` outside of template context. It does *not* generally improve readability or the code's "kung-fu level".

Note that in retrospect, `std::result_of` adds to the code's "kung-fu level" even more than just using `decltype`. This does not make using `decltype` for this kind of thing OK.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Try and write a reasonable-looking `result_of` invocation outside of templates (without using `decltype`).

Comment: @Xeo I found it! (after a long search of what abysmal sequence of characters I needed to please the compiler, I found them on cplusplus.com of all places) No, I am not proud of the result.

Comment: Hey, I said "without `decltype`". You use `decltype` inside your `result_of` invocation. :P

Comment: @Xeo You edited that in, I didn't refresh the page :-P. I still don't see the point of ever wanting to do this.